# fill into the a vector holding pointers to lists

Tags: c++, list, vector, graph

I initialize a vector of pointers each pointing to a list of neighbors to implement adjacency-list representation of Graph.

```
class Graph
{
public:
     Graph(int V) : vertices(V) {}
     // Member functions for Graph class
     void addEdge();
     void print();
     void type(string);
private:
     vector<list<int> *> vertices;
};
```

addEdge function asks the user to enter the edge from what vertex to another. I think there's a mistake somewhere in filling the vector.

```
void Graph::addEdge()
{
    int v, w;
    cout << "\nvertex: ";
    cin >> v;
    cout << "\nadjacent: ";
    cin >> w;
    vertices[v]->push_back(w);
}
```

I need help in this if this is the right way of filling the data structure I introduced or not! if not, what would be the right way of performing the task?

Comment: Why does the vector contain pointers? Do you allocate and add those lists anywhere?

Comment: The same question I asked in [your previous question](stackoverflow.comAC/questions/23415287/initializing-a-vector-to-a-list-of-integers) applies here: why do you need to store pointers to lists?

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel you could use `boost::graph`.

Comment: @molbdnilo -because the adjacency-list representation of graph requires an array/vector holding pointer to an array/vector/list which contains the adjacents of a specific vertex.

Comment: @juanchopanza -storing pointers brings the memory-efficient concept in the case if a vertex does not have a adjacent at all. Any suggestion what could be right approach?

Comment: I don't see how that could help memory efficiency, whatever that is. I already suggested an approach in your previous question.

Comment: @mehdix_ The adjacency list representation doesn't require pointers, it requires a collection with dynamic size. `vector` and `list` are such collections, and `vector` is usually more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a `std::vector<std::vector>` for the [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of your graph and I advice you not to mix UI with your class (see code below):

```
class Graph
{
public:
  Graph(std::size_t const n_vert) : adjmat(n_vert, std::vector<int>(n_vert)) {}
     // Member functions for Graph class
     void addEdge(std::size_t const from, std::size_t const to, int const weight);
     void print();
     void type(std::string);
private:
     std::vector<std::vector<int>> adjmat;
};

void Graph::addEdge(std::size_t const from, std::size_t const to, int const weight = 1)
{
  // or `adjmat.at(from).at(to)` for range checking
  adjmat[from][to] = weight;
}

int main ()
{
    Graph G(10);
    int v, w;
    std::cout << "\nvertex: ";
    std::cin  >> v;
    std::cout << "\nadjacent: ";
    std::cin  >> w;
    G.addEdge(v, w);

    return 0;
}
```

This solution is recommended though, for small Graphs.

Comment: It should always be mentioned, that `std::vector<std::vector>` is only reasonable with C++11 move semantics. For those stuck with C++03, [Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/libs/container/) can emulate it well enough for this purpose.